# sql query get row id in other column

Tags: sql

I am trying an exercise. How can I get specific rows from a resultset of another query?
example:

```
ID1   ID2
1     3
2     4
3     5
4     3
5     3
6     4
```

and the result should be like this

```
ID1   ID2
3     5
4     3
5     3
```

thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific ?

Comment: you should study joins

Comment: What is this 'other query'. What is the selection of ID's based on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a join with a derived table:

```
SELECT myTable.*
FROM myTable
INNER JOIN (/*my other query*/) q ON myTable.id = q.id
```

Or a subquery with `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE id IN (/*my other query*/)
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT **distinct** *
FROM Table
WHERE ID IN ( /* other query */ )